# R How to subset datatable with higher values of a column (so that the subset represent 80% of the column sum)

Tags: r, subset

I've got a datatable with factors and numeric values. What I want is to subset this datatable to select only the higher values.The sum of these higher values must represent 80% of the column sum.

Is ther an elegant way of doing that ?

For instance, here is an unordered datatable, `ECART_H` column contain the value of interest (`sum = 10307.08`; `0.8*sum = 8245`) the subsetting should result in selecting only row 3: and 4: (`sum= 8428`) so that these 2 rows are the minimum rows to select for being >80% of the sum of `ECART_H`.

```
  REGROUP FAMILLE      TREND       RMSE    ECART_H
1:      10     A03   48.43853   675.7492  470.45737
2:      10     A04   61.65814   599.2031  795.08575
3:      10     H01  269.07728 12004.1214 6974.29642
4:      10     N01 -170.30563  6282.8133 1455.44291
5:      10     S01  147.61121  2711.0511  529.22545
6:      10     D06   13.64792   167.9315   82.57669
```

Comment: How many values are considered as higher values?  Perhaps `library(zoo);df1[df1[, which(rollsum(ECART_H, 2) > (0.8 * sum(ECART_H))) + 0:1]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution using cume_dist. The mutate is shown for convenience and I am not sure if you needed the grouping.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(REGROUP) %>%
  arrange(ECART_H)  %>%
  mutate(c = cume_dist(ECART_H)) %>%
  filter(c >= 0.8)

#   REGROUP FAMILLE     TREND      RMSE  ECART_H         c
#     <int>   <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1      10     N01 -170.3056  6282.813 1455.443 0.8333333
# 2      10     H01  269.0773 12004.121 6974.296 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 2):

I did this:

```
df <- df[order(-df$ECART_H),]

df$cumsum <- cumsum(df$ECART_H)

df$cumfreq <- cumsum(df$ECART_H)/sum(df$ECART_H)

df <- df[ (df$cumsum <= 0.8), ]
```

But these two values (row 3: and 4:) is 81,8%, which is higher than 80%.

Answer (score 0):

Ok based on epi99 answer with some modifications : arrange from larger value to smaller value, then perform a cumsum rather than a cumdist, then filter.

This way i've got only the first lines that represent in value 80% of the sum of all values. (This is for example to work on Pareto' method manner and focus on what's important)

```
test <- dfCONSO_FAM_TREND %>%
  group_by(REGROUP) %>%
  filter(ECART_H>0) %>%
  arrange(-ECART_H)  %>%
  mutate(pc=ECART_H/sum(ECART_H)*100) %>%
  mutate(pcCUM=cumsum(pc))

dfFOCUS_FAM <- dfFOCUS_FAM[(dfFOCUS_FAM$pc>=80 | dfFOCUS_FAM$pcCUM<=80),]
```

The last data.table filter has been added to select rows of interest. Big row (representing >=80% of the sum) and/or rows that until reaching 80% of the sum (selecting rows until reaching 80% of the sum (p.ex. filter(pcCUM<=80) ) will results in selecting no lines if one rows represent more than 80% of the sum)

DPLYR rocks and data.table too

If one could translate the first part in data.table language...